# Create and download zip in PHP

Tags: php, zip

I have the following code:

```
    // start downloading
    require_once 'classes/class-FlxZipArchive.php';

    $filename = 'update_'.time();

    $path = 'updates'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$update;

    $zip = new FlxZipArchive;

    $zip->open($filename.'.zip',ZipArchive::CREATE);

    $zip->addDir($path,basename($path));

    $zip->close();

    if(file_exists($filename.'.zip')){

        header("Content-type: application/zip"); 

        header("Cache-Control: public");

        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");

        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename.".zip");

        header("Content-length: ".filesize($filename.'.zip'));

        header("Pragma: no-cache"); 

        header("Expires: 0"); 

        readfile($filename.'.zip');

        unlink($filename.'.zip');

    };

    exit;
```

This works, but the problem is: not the zip is downloaded, but an unzipped version of the zip. The zip is created and is visible on the server, but it downloads an unzipped version of the zip.

Let's say i have files.zip with the following content:

```
- folder
    - images
        - image1.png
        - image2.png
    - docs
        - doc1.docx
        - doc2.docx
```

Then the zip is created but **not** downloaded. Instead, a normal map with name 'folder' is downloaded (unzipped).

Where is my mistake?

I use the following class: https://gist.github.com/panslaw/4327882

**Edit:**

the code is working as expected, but I was using a mac with the settings to download and extract "save" files automatically. More info here: https://wiki.umbc.edu/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=31919091

Comment: can you explain *a normal map with name 'folder' is downloaded (unzipped)*, the code is working as expected for me.

Comment: You should be very careful with it, as if `$path` is ever empty it will attempt to zip the entire system from `/`.

Comment: the problem is that - while downloading - it seems like  the zip-file is already extracted. When I click my download button, I don't get the zip-file (but the zip-file is created and stored on the server) but I get only the content of the zip-file.

Comment: I'm still confused with *I get only the content of the zip-file* can you show a screenshot, a browser wont download a folder and its contents.

Comment: Ok I found my problem! I'll edit my question... it's pretty stupid tbh...

Comment: what was it? Im intrigued

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help Lawrence! When you said "the code is working as expected for me" I figured out it had something to do with my computer, and not with my code...

Comment: oh its a mac thing, ruddy computers..

Answer (score 0):

Please try that code :

**Html:**

```
<div class='container'>
 <h1>Create and Download Zip file using PHP</h1>
 <form method='post' action=''>
  <input type='submit' name='create' value='Create Zip' />&nbsp;
  <input type='submit' name='download' value='Download' />
 </form>
</div>
```

**Php**

I have created includes folder within the project where I stored some files and folders.

**Create Zip**

Create ZipArchive Class object for Zip file creation. Define a function createZip() to read files and directory from the specified directory path.

**If file**

If the reading value is the file then add it to zip object using addFile() method.

If directory

If the value is directory then create an empty directory and call createZip() function where pass the directory path.

**Download Zip**

Check if zip file exists or not. If it exists then download and remove it from the server.

```
<?php 
// Create ZIP file
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
 $zip = new ZipArchive();
 $filename = "./myzipfile.zip";

 if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
  exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
 }

 $dir = 'includes/';

 // Create zip
 createZip($zip,$dir);

 $zip->close();
}

// Create zip
function createZip($zip,$dir){
 if (is_dir($dir)){

  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
   while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){

    // If file
    if (is_file($dir.$file)) {
     if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

      $zip->addFile($dir.$file);
     }
    }else{
     // If directory
     if(is_dir($dir.$file) ){

      if($file != '' && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){

       // Add empty directory
       $zip->addEmptyDir($dir.$file);

       $folder = $dir.$file.'/';

       // Read data of the folder
       createZip($zip,$folder);
      }
     }

    }

   }
   closedir($dh);
  }
 }
}

// Download Created Zip file
if(isset($_POST['download'])){

 $filename = "myzipfile.zip";

 if (file_exists($filename)) {
  header('Content-Type: application/zip');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filename).'"');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));

  flush();
  readfile($filename);
  // delete file
  unlink($filename);

 }
}
?>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 50%;
 text-align: center;
}

input[type=submit]{
 border: none;
 padding: 7px 15px;
 font-size: 16px;
 background-color: #00a1a1;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Check that [link](http://makitweb.com/how-to-create-and-download-a-zip-file-with-php/)